# Why does Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Result throw an exception if Task<HttpResponseMessage>.IsCompleted is true?

Tags: c#, async-await, httpresponsemessage

This only occurs under heavy load so I can't put up a simple example. This is for a system test so I'm trying to avoid await and instead I'm creating 2,000 requests and then polling for when the responses complete.

The problematic code is:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = responseStatus.Item1;
if (!response.IsCompleted)
    continue;
HttpResponseMessage result = response.Result;
```

Where the call to Result throws the following:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
StackTrace:       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at SystemTests.V2.LoadTests.Test1000Requests() in C:\git\Jenova\restfulengine\SystemTests.V2\LoadTests.cs:line 121
INNER EXCEPTION:    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
StackTrace:    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at SystemTests.V2.LoadTests.Test1000Requests() in C:\git\Jenova\restfulengine\SystemTests.V2\LoadTests.cs:line 121
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

2020-04-26 13:36:06,370 [MSTestAdapter Thread] WARN SystemTests.V2.LoadTests - v2/reports/19ea788d-ceb8-4a81-a974-f597494609dd failed (will retry)System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at SystemTests.V2.LoadTests.Test1000Requests() in C:\git\Jenova\restfulengine\SystemTests.V2\LoadTests.cs:line 121
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Task.IsCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted?view=netcore-3.1) is "true if the task has completed (that is, the task is in one of the three final states: RanToCompletion, Faulted, or Canceled); otherwise, false."

So if the HTTP request fails in a way that doesn't create a usable `HttpResponseMessage` you can't access the Result.  So check the Task.Status to see which it is.

Comment: That was it. I assumed IsCompleted meant successfully. Yeah - I should have read the docs closely.

Comment: @DavidThielen and rightly so. In .NET Core they have added the property [`IsCompletedSuccessfully`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompletedsuccessfully). Unfortunately this useful property is not available in .NET Framework (and probably will never be).